# Camel Twitter endpoint - Metadata and atttributes

Tags: twitter, apache-camel

Cam anyone suggest if there is anyway to retrieve all the attributes and metadata for Twitter Streaming endpoint supported by Camel. This is the routing definition I have and this only returns the Time and Tweet text, not the other attributes and metadata that are stored in the Status object -

```
from("twitter://streaming/filter?type=event&keywords=" + searchTerm)
        .convertBodyTo(String.class)
        .to("log:tweet")
```

Here's the output for eg -

```
Tue Sep 03 14:08:27 EDT 2013 (Pritz97) I love the new design! http://t.co/c8CTccjGBJ's latest iOS version is now live! #iosapp #iPhone http://t.co/hG1KEgvfruTue 
Tue Sep 03 14:10:50 EDT 2013 (l1v1nfunky) Reign of Dragons iOS/Android #ReignD http://t.co/lVtd5cWTkZ
```

Please suggest how can I get all data/attributes.
Thanks!
Chriatie

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you convert the body to a String so it does a toString of the twitter body. If you do NOT do that then you have all the meta-data of the tweet which twitter4j library offers.

Comment: Thanks Claus! If i remove convertBody, how do I retrieve all attributes from the Twitter Status object, assuming I push the data to ActiveMQ. I'm sorry this question sounds silly.

Comment: I've started using Camel, and dont have good knowledge abt Twiter endpoint. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: You need to use the message translator eip to transform the message into what you want. For example you can use a java bean to do that, or what you want to do. Read about the eip at: http://camel.apache.org/message-translator.html

Comment: I would like to vote for the ans, but it seems it requires me to have 15 reputations etc.

Comment: No problem, maybe you can mark this question as answered? That may grow your reputation?